# StreamReader ReadLine() for CSV files

Tags: c#, readline, streamreader

I am trying to use this code to create a list.  It is failing at the NewCrime Convert step.  Not sure how to use the stream reader.  It is my first time and I usually use SQL so I have attempted to do the same thing I would do reading SQL here.

List MasterCrimeList;

```
    public List<Crime.Crime> GetList()
    {
        MasterCrimeList = new List<Crime.Crime>();

        try
        {

            string path = @"F:\\FanshaweCollegeClasses\\Winter2020\\CLAYS_FINAL_EXAM_2020\\VANHEESfinalEXAM\\SacramentocrimeJanuary2006.csv";
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                // Open the file to read from.
                using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
                {
                    string s;
                    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        Crime.Crime NewCrime = new Crime.Crime(Convert.ToString(s[0]),//CrimeDateTime
                                              Convert.ToString(s[1]),//CrimeAddress
                                              Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(s[2])),//CrimeDistrict
                                              Convert.ToString(s[3]),//CrimeBeat
                                              Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(s[4])),//CrimeGrid
                                              Convert.ToString(s[5]),//CrimeDescription
                                              Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(s[6])),//ncicCode
                                              decimal.Parse(Convert.ToString(s[7])),//Latitude DECIMAL
                                              decimal.Parse(Convert.ToString(s[8])));//Longitude DECIMAL

                        MasterCrimeList.Add(NewCrime);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please check how you should use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: You are passing characters from the _s_ variable to your fields. Probably you need to split the string loaded with ReadLine using some kind of separator. String.Split is the tool for this task

Comment: what's the error you're getting? `ReadLine` returns the line as a string, you don't need to convert it to a string each time. Also, `s[0]` and others will give you only one char. If it is a csv file, you need to read each value separated by comma from the string.

Answer (score 0):

When doing `s[0]` you're reading only one char of the whole line. What you should do is to split each line based on how the values are stored using [`Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1), and then you can access each value as an array. If it's a csv file:

```
                string s;
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] lineValues = s.Split(new char[]{','});
                    string firstValue = lineValues[0];
                    string secondValue = lineValues[1];
                    ...
                }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will try that.  I was thinking that I might need to do something like that but didn't know how.

Comment: I tried that and it is giving me an error saying that it can't convert a string to char.  It is underlining in red the (",") part.

Comment: @Geode I see, that depends on the .net version you're compiling this into. Please check my last update: `s.Split(new char[]{','});` should work for you.